# Unable to login docker registry in Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

I have a docker registry setup in Artifactory and I am trying to login but I keep getting Forbidden message

When I execute

```
docker login art.example.com

Output:
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx
Error response from daemon: Get https://art.example.com/v2/: unknown: Forbidden
```

Artifactory logs show:
    `20180510195825|1|REQUEST|XX.XX.XX.XX|non_authenticated_user|GET|/api/docker/v2/|HTTP/1.1|403|0`

Any help would be appreciated.

***Update:***

**Fixed (2019-01-09):**
Changed proxy (nginx) with the following:

```
(...)

listen 443 ssl;

(...)

# Docker traffic
# Redirect (most) requests to /v2/* to the Docker Registry
location /v2/ {
    add_header 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version' $docker_distribution_api_version always;
    rewrite ^/(v2)/$ /api/docker/$1;
    rewrite ^/(v2)/([^\/]*)/(.*) /api/docker/$2/$1/$3;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

# Artifactory traffic
location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/artifactory/(.*)$ ) {
        proxy_pass          http://art.example.com:8081/artifactory/$1;
    }

    proxy_pass_header       Server;
    proxy_pass              http://art.example.com:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host/artifactory;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the user is not reaching to Artifactory, as you can see in the request.log that you posted. I would start by looking at the reverse proxy configuration and check why is the user not being passed to Artifactory

Comment: Hi! Were you able to solve your isue? I'm encountering the same error.

Comment: @Squirrel were u able to resolve this problem? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @KrisT  see update above. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @Charlie updated post